# how to add a new column into a table using set type which values are from a select statement?

Tags: sql, set, alter

I want to add a new column into a table, say table1, using type SET.  The values in set need to be from values a column from other table, say table2 like:

table2:

```
name
-------
name1
name2
name2
```

so I want to have a new column in table1 with set('name1', 'name2', 'name3')

How can I make a workable sql statement like:

```
ALTER TABLE `table2` ADD `new_column` SET(`select name from table2`)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create an ALTER statement which add a new column:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD new_column type;
```

After the statement has been successfully executed, you can now update all the records:

```
UPDATE  table1 
SET     new_column = 'value'
```

Alternative you can add a default value:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD new_column type [NOT NULL] [DEFAULT ('default value')]
```

Comment: No, I don't want to insert any new record into to table1. All I want is to have a column whose type is SET(all possible names from table2)